# Flutter cloud firestore range base query

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, composite-index

**What I'm trying to do:**

I have a collection called "Users" where each user(document) has its own latitude and longitude saved inside of that file. With that, I'm trying to do a query which will look something like this.

```
_firestore
        .collection('Users')
        .where('lat', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: docLat)
        .where('lat', isLessThanOrEqualTo: maxLat)
        .where('lon', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: docLon)
        .where('lon', isLessThanOrEqualTo: maxLon)
```

---

**Error:**

> PlatformException (PlatformException(error, All where filters other
>   than whereEqualTo() must be on the same field. But you have filters on
>   'lat' and 'lon', null))

---

**Problems:**

1. I can not use **GeoPoint** as type in my document. Why? Because if I will search base on that, something like this:

`_firestore
        .collection('Users')
        .where('geopoint', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: myGeopoint)
        .where('geopoint', isLessThanOrEqualTo: limitGeopoint)`

is not going to work because it will comper just the **Latitude** of my GeoPoint, and the **Longitude** is going to be ignored.

2. I can not use **Geohash**. If will compare them in the same way as I did with GeoPoints it will fail to show me all the results because the way how geohash works.
3. I know about some packages like [firestore_helpers](https://pub.dev/packages/firestore_helpers) or [geoflutterfire](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire). But the problem with those is that **I CAN NOT** limit the result set. I etcher get all of them or not. Or if have any idea how can I limit them let me know (no, I don't want to limit the collection result, before the data is going to be sent to one of those packages, check my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56674470/flutter-firestore-geo-query))

---

**What I've tried to do:**

I head about **Composite Index** used in firebase and I've made them like this.
[image]

But the query is still not working and I wasn't able to find any example with composite index yet used in flutter (or at least dart) for my case.

So far as I understood I need to use the Compose Index something like this.

```
 _firestore
        .collection('Users')
        .where('lat_lon', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: userData.geopoint.latitude.toString() + "_0.0")
        .where('lat_lon', isLessThanOrEqualTo: maxLimit.latitude.toString() + "_0.0")
        .where('lat_lon', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:  "0.0_" + userData.geopoint.longitude.toString())
        .where('lat_lon', isLessThanOrEqualTo: "0.0_" +maxLimit.longitude.toString())
```

But is not working either. Do you have any solution for me? I really need to find a way to fix this.

Comment: You can't have range filters on multiple fields in Firestore. The marked duplicate gives some alternatives.  Usually this involves filtering on the client.

Comment: In this case, what's the purpose of Compose Index then? Nobody talks about it.

Comment: Combining a single ranged filter with one or more equality filters.