# GeoflutterFire for Firestore : with search centered on same set of data locations, Query result succeeds or fails depending of the radius

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, geohashing

The radius parameter on GeoflutterFire library has a weird behaviour.

Centering a search on some specific location with known existing results :

setting approximately 1 km radius , there will be some results

setting approximately 1.5 km radius, there will be not results anymore

setting approximately 2km radius, there will be again some results

around and superior to 4 km, most of the first results will be at the extreme of the radius

Does someone manage to create a working case with this library? I would be surprised if this is due to limitation of geohash. I would think more of an error in this library making it pretty useless in a production app if results are not coherent

Can you advise another similar library on Flutter?
`

```
Geoflutterfire geo = Geoflutterfire();
    GeoFirePoint center =
        geo.point(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude);

Query collectionQuery =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('places');

return geo
    .collection(collectionRef: collectionQuery)
    .within(
        center: center,
        radius: filter.radius!,
        field: 'location',
        strictMode: true)
    .map((snapshots) {}`
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a better solution? I am facing a similar problem and read in another question that someone gave up on Flutter for this and switched to Parse Server: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56674470/flutter-firestore-geo-query

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer lays there, which makes me wonder how other app manage to have a proper location filtration whatever the radius.
Do they use library without geohash?
The current limitation makes the library useless per my point of view

> Usage of strictMode
>
> It's advisable to use strictMode = false for smaller radius to make
> use of documents from neighbouring hashes as well.
>
> As the radius increases to a large number, the neighbouring hash
> precisions fetch documents which would be considerably far from the
> radius bounds, hence its advisable to use strictMode = true for larger
> radius.
>
> Note: filtering for strictMode happens on client side, hence filtering
> at larger radius is at the expense of making unnecessary document
> reads.